# I have a hex string like this 58FF1CE5.This is corresponding to One date time 16/09/1955 .(ie in MM/dd/yyyy).How can i do this in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a hex string like this 58FF1CE5.This is corresponding to One date time 16/09/1955 .(ie in MM/dd/yyyy).How can i do this in ObjectiveC, I am getting this date in didDiscovercharacterstcs

Comment: While the answer of CodeChanger is correct for the question that you asked (converting a hex NSString to a NSDate), I **strongly** suspect that from bluetooth you are getting `NSData` and when you log it, it is showing the values as hex.  If that is the case, you should modify your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to convert your Hex String into Date for that you can use below code for conversion.

```
unsigned result = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"58FF1CE5"];
[scanner scanHexInt:&result];
NSTimeInterval interval = (NSTimeInterval)result;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
```

From NSDate to Hex String use below code :

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [<YOUR_DATE> timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *strHexInterval = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x", (int)interval];
NSLog(@"Hex Interval Value %@", strHexInterval);
```

Hope this will helps!

Comment: Thank, You saved my day..I was making silly mistake :)

Comment: How I can do vice versa..mean NSdate to HexaValue..I m getting time stamp as integer value